# Python subprocess throwing an error while using unix join command

Tags: python, unix, subprocess

I am trying to use subprocess for joining 2 files after sorting them.  But I am getting the following error. Did try escaping '/', didn't help either.

```
cmd = "join --nocheck-order -t/: <(sort file1) <(sort file2)"
proc = subprocess.Popen([cmd], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE, shellresult = proc.communicate()
print result

('', '/bin/sh: 1: Syntax error: "(" unexpected\n')
```

Comment: A posix-standard `/bin/sh` won't understand `<(command)` syntax. Need to run that using bash, zsh, ksh93, or another shell that does.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are having problems with the `<(sort file)` syntax. Try to use *shell=True* argument in *Popen()*